# .apk file of my android app is not getting data from oracle database (Connected through LAN). but works good on emulator

Tags: java, android, oracle, android-studio

I am building an Android application for order placement for a car showroom. My customer already has an installed Oracle database where their data is stored. My customer asked me to synchronize this Android application with his old database.

I made an Android application that can connect to database using JSBC.

When I run this Android application on an Android emulator it property retrieves data from oracle database. But when I build its .apk file and install it on mobile, its not getting data from database.
Note: remember my database is installed of server and my laptop is connected through LAN.

Comment: Android != Java EE

Comment: Is your phone connected to the same LAN as well?

Comment: Please read: [JDBC vs Web Service for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15853367/295004)

Comment: yes Agu Thadeus he is connected with same network.

Comment: Some grammar and capitalization edits